# PowerShell deletion script that looks at folder time stamp and not on files

Tags: powershell

I have a script that auto-deletes files older than x-days.

```
$dump_path = "C:\Backup\GroupPolicies"
$max_days = "-7"
$curr_date = Get-Date
$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)
Get-ChildItem $dump_path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

However, i want it to look for the ***folder time stamp instead of the file time stamp***. Is there such way to do this? I've searched everywhere but all i see is on file time stamp.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. What have you attempted? Please add the attempt to your question

Comment: What do you mean by "delete files by looking at folder time stamp"? Which folder? Which timestamp (created, modified)? I imagine you mean "delete folders (and their contents) by looking at the folder's created date"? If so, `Get-ChildItem -Directory | ? CreationTime -lt $del_date` will get you the folders, then remove those. Don't bother checking individual files. If that's not what you mean, then explain more...

Answer (score 2):

If you were limited to PowerShell 2.0 you do something like this although it is a little inefficient.

```
Get-ChildItem $dump_path -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | 
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$False -Force -WhatIf
```

Get all the folder matching the date criteria. Then for each of those folder get all the child items withing. This could include more folders. So if your hierarchy is complicated this will fall apart and more complex logic would be required.

Using `-WhatIf` to be sure the code isolated the files you want it to be.

---

With PowerShell at least 3.0 then you could use the `-Directory` switch parameter of `Get-ChildItem`

```
Get-ChildItem $dump_path -Recurse -Directory | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | 
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$False -Force -WhatIf
```